# manually stopping cargo container Tomcat 6.X

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I am using Maven 2.2.0. I am using the Maven Cargo plugin for deployment. The server is Tomcat 6.X

We generally use `mvn cargo:stop` to stop the container.

Is there any manual method to do it?

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know in what context you need it, but when my tomcat server hangs (started with cargo), I mostly kill it by finding and killing the `java` process:

```
ps -ef | grep tomcat
kill -9 <pid>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually when I trying to run cargo:stop, it is hanging. I am running a Java web application through this. To stop it, I want to find out other ways.

Comment: What do you mean by it's hanging ? No messages on the command waiting for shutdown etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Cargo uses Tomcat [manager's text API](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Stop_an_Existing_Application) if I'm not mistaken. Of course you could issue the same request manually or login to the manager app (HTML UI) and click the stop button but you'd see the same result. Tomcat, the entire server, cannot be stopped remotely. However, you can try `telnet server 8005` and send `SHUTDOWN` and see if that's permitted or not.